# VBA script error 80070005 (access denied) on Oshell.Exec

Tags: vba

The full error I get is this:
Run-time error -2147024891 (80070005):
The strange thing is that I don't always get the error. Some days it works fine, some days I only get the error. I have also tried to run the command manually in a command prompt without Admin rights.

Debug shows that is hangs on this line:
`Set oExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd)`

Where sCmd = `C:\Program Files\ANSYS Inc\Shared Files\Licensing\winx64\lmutil lmstat -c 1055@ansyslmserver -f`

This is the whole sub:

```
Public Function ShellRun(sCmd As String) As String

    'Run a shell command, returning the output as a string

    Dim oShell As Object
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    'run command
    Dim oExec As Object
    Dim oOutput As Object
    Set oExec = oShell.Exec(sCmd)
    Set oOutput = oExec.StdOut

    'handle the results as they are written to and read from the StdOut object
    Dim s As String
    Dim sLine As String
    While Not oOutput.AtEndOfStream
        sLine = oOutput.ReadLine
        If sLine <> "" Then s = s & sLine & vbCrLf
    Wend

    ShellRun = s

End Function
```

Thanks a lot for any input!

Answer (score 0):

Opening a command prompt as ADMIN and running:
`regsvr32 quartz.dll`
solved the issue.

Unfortunately the problem started again after restarting the computer.